# How to overcome NoReverseMatch for link inside if statement in the template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to make some value if they exist to be links.
In some case value will be None and in some case, it will have a record that user should be able to click at.

So in my template, I put it inside the if statement

```
{% if expense_row.noteextra.extra.id  %} <a href="{% url
'extra_notes_details' pk=expense_row.noteextra.extra.id %}" class="btn
btn-info">{{ expense_row.noteextra}}</a> 
                  {% else %}
                   {{ expense_row.noteextra}}

                 {% endif %}
```

But despite the if statement I still get error

> NoReverseMatch at /expense/list/range/

```
Reverse for 'extra_notes_details' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['unit/extra_notes_details/(?P<pk>\\d+)$']
```

It means that Django template is being parsed  for urls in early stage and it
doesn't care if those non-operational urls are inside if statement or even commented out -it will just dump an error.

How can I build those occasional links without getting the error?

Comment: Your template uses `unit_notes_details` which doesn’t match `extra_notes_details` from the error. The error is coming from somewhere else.

Comment: yeah, I used diffrent sample in my question. Fixed it .

Comment: Previous answer solved my problem but it was deleted for some reason

Comment: In your updated question, `if expense_row.noteunit.unit.id` doesn't match `pk=expense_row.noteextra.extra.id` in the url tag. If you check `expense_row.noteextra.extra.id` in the template, then the url tag won't be evaluated and you shouldn't get a `NoReverseMatch` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add method to the model:

```
def unit_url(self):
    unit_id = getattr(self.noteunit.unit, 'id', None)
    if unit_id:
        return reverse('extra_notes_details', kwargs={'pk': unit_id})
```

and use it in template:

```
{% if expense_row.unit_url %}
    {{ expense_row.unit_url }}
{% else %}
    {{ expense_row.noteunit}}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`{% url %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#url) tag lets you assign the result to a variable. This *will not* raise an error if it fails to reverse the URL.

```
{% url 'extra_notes_details' pk=expense_row.noteextra.extra.id as the_url %}"

{% if the_url %}
  <a href="{{ the_url }}" class="btn btn-info">{{ expense_row.noteextra}}</a>
{% else %}
  {{ expense_row.noteextra}}
{% endif %}
```